# MySQL ALL Combinations from Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables set out like so...

```
table1
league, date

table2
league, team
```

What I need to do is get all possible combinations when the leagues match each other.

So for example in table1 I will have..

```
Bel1, 39319
Bel1, 39320
Ita1, 39321
```

and in table2 for example..

```
Bel1, Anderlecht
Bel1, Bergen
Bel1, Dender
```

and the output would have to give me..

```
Bel1, 39319, Anderlecht
Bel1, 39319, Bergen
Bel1, 39319, Dener
Bel1, 39320, Anderlecht
Bel1, 39320, Bergen
Bel1, 39320, Dener
```

Would this be possible? I have tried doing it in excel but for the amount of data I need processed it would be over a million rows and VERY time consuming so I am hoping that I can do it in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a `cross join`.  You can use it as:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

However, I suspect that you really want a regular join:

```
select t1.*, t2.col1
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1;
```

Your sample data has no output for `'Ita1'`, suggesting that you actually want a match.

Comment: Otherwise known as a cartesian product. Also note that as of MySQL 5, `JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, and `CROSS JOIN` are synonyms.

Comment: @JaredFarrish . . . I would never note that, because I think it is a very bad idea and violates the standard.